# get screenshot for a ScrollView in worker thread

Tags: android, multithreading, screenshot, android-scrollview

I need to get screenshot for a ScrollView. My code is as bellow:

```
private File getScreenShot() {
    final int count = mScrollView.getChildCount();
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View view = mScrollView.getChildAt(i);
        height += view.getHeight();
    }

    // get screen shot bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mScrollView.getWidth(), height,
            Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    mScrollView.draw(canvas);

    // save to a temp file
    return saveToFile(bitmap);
}
```

Because my `mScrollView` is so long that some of content will be hidden until user scrolls down, it spends much time capturing the screenshot(nearly 100ms) and temporarily stops the UI thread. So I decide to run the method in another thread. Code likes:

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        mShareFile = getScreenShot();
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(96);
    }
}.start();
```

But something interesting came: I tried to use a subclass of `Thread` and `AsyncTask`. Each of them can do the job in most time. However, in a few times an exception will be thrown and cause app crash:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

But how can I run the code successfully in most time? I mean, if I can get this exception, indeed I did something wrong(call `View.draw(Canvas)` outside main thread). The failure won't happen for the first or second time running the code while it can happen for the third time. And I tried to scroll the `ScrollView` and call the method before scrolling stops, it may cause the crash. But if I do the same thing for the first time, crash won't happen, either.

I output the thread, it belongs to main group -> [Thread XXXXX, 5, main]

I don't know why this strange result happened? Can someone tell me the reason? How can I get screenshot of a `ScrollView` in another thread?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt try to take a screenshot from another thread. I would take the screenshot from the main thread and save it to disk on another thread.

Have you tried the drawing cache?

```
mScrollView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mScrollView.getDrawingCache());
mScrollView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

If it does not improve performance, I would take a screenshot of the children of mScrollView and assemble them into one bitmap on another thread. It would allow you to yield the UI thread between children.

Comment: Drawing cache is useless, it will create a null bitmap for scrollview.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Also just verified an old project and canvas is how I did it too. Didnt have any issue tough so I assume your screen is loaded with views :). I'd still go with the childrens instead of the scrollview